# Insert modeshape into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, modeshape

I want to know is there any tutorial or program that shows all necessary actions for to create nodes in modeshape and to store in a SQL Server database?

I'm well struggling with this new technology and I don't have any help around.

With the help of some experts I have some global ideas

On start the engine: create a session and create nodes save the session and shut down the engine.

I want to know how he makes the link with the database.

I have created the nodes.

1. I have installed SQL jdbc with the help of maven
2. I have added the `dependencyin pom.xml` file.
3. I want to know should I do things in `config.json`?
4. What should I do in `infinspan.xml`?
5. How they store in database (either by an insert)?

I badly need some help.

Thanks for your precious help

Comment: Please read [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

1&2 no problem at all

3 nothing, as long as it works with default settings

5 I don't know, maybe Randall Hauch can answer about it.

4 compared to the example given from git(),here's something you needed to edit, pay attention to everything begin with an '#'

```
<persistence passivation="false">
<stringKeyedJdbcStore xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:jdbc:6.0"
    fetchPersistentState="false"
    ignoreModifications="false"
    purgeOnStartup="false">
<connectionPool
        connectionUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=#YourDBName;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
        driverClass="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        username="#yourusername"
        password="#yourpassword"/>
<stringKeyedTable
        prefix="ISPN_STRING_TABLE"
        createOnStart="true"
        dropOnExit="false">
    <idColumn name="ID_COLUMN" type="#NVARCHAR(255)"/>
    <dataColumn name="DATA_COLUMN" type="#VARBINARY(MAX)"/>
    <timestampColumn name="TIMESTAMP_COLUMN" type="BIGINT"/>
</stringKeyedTable>
</stringKeyedJdbcStore>
</persistence>
```

ps: Why varbinary(max)? I don't know... The binary data inserted is only around 10 kbits at size, but IT WILL GO WRONG with binary(8000), or any number smaller.

pps: Why NVARCHAR(255)?

> You need to make the ID_COLUMN in Infinispan NVARCHAR not VARCHAR, because Unicode support is required. See [Re: Modeshape with MS SQL Server 2008 \ 2010](https://community.jboss.org/message/866739#866739) for the similar issue.--Horia Chiorean from https://community.jboss.org/en/modeshape

ppps: He answered the question in the minute I posted...